# C# lose modal property during enabled and disabled form

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to block gui in multi thread application, do my action and then enable application.
Change Enable property on Form component do exatly what I want. But in simple example I have form1 and form2. I show modal form2 on form1, and then I can't click on form1, it's normal.
After disable and enable those forms this behaviour is lost, I can click on form1.
I want to prevent this.

Thank's for help

Comment: what exactly are you disabling/enabling? It almost sounds like you're implementing your own modality through disabling the previous form.